# Chrome extension popup has a 2 - 3 second delay

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I have a todo list [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-tasks/bngpflcpbefndiblbdjokgpmbldcoplk) where all of the code is in the content. There's nothing in `background.js` – mainly because I also deploy this app as a [standalone website.](http://supersimpletasks.com/)

There's a 2 - 3 second delay between clicking on the extension's browser action and the popup rendering. I believe it's because Chrome is waiting before a lot of JS is run before showing the popup.

What's weird is that it loads instantly when I open the app as a tab (it's not a particularly heavy JS app!) It only shows a massive delay as a popup.

Without fundamentally changing the architecture of my extension, is there a way I can get some quick wins to improve the loading performance of the popup? What can I defer?

Here's my `manifest.json` file:

```
"background": {
  "page": "index.html"
},

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {   
    "19": "img/icon19.png",
    "38": "img/icon38.png"
  },

"default_title": "Super Simple Tasks",

"default_popup": "index.html?popup=true"
}
```

The app does a few things in `$(document).ready`: setting a class on the body, putting some things into the console, checking the storage type, and checking whether we have an internet connection.

Note: If you prefer JavaScript, [here is the compiled JS code](http://pastebin.com/6st4ZxHs) that runs on each load. There's a bit more there than what I've included below.

```
$(document).ready ->

  setPopupClass()

  standardLog()

  checkStorageMethod()

  checkOnline()

  $new_task_input = $('#new-task')
  $link_input = $('#add-link-input')

  initialize()
```

`initialize` then sets up the app: It gets the array of tasks and checks whether it's empty, it sends an event to Google Analytics, runs a migration from an old version if necessary, shows the tasks, and does some DOM manipulation.

```
initialize = ->

    window.storageType.get DB.db_key, (allTasks) ->

      if allTasks == null
        allTasks = Arrays.default_data
        window.storageType.set(DB.db_key, allTasks)

      ga 'send',
      'hitType': 'event'
      'eventCategory': 'Data'
      'eventAction': 'Task count'
      'eventValue': allTasks.length

      Migrations.run(allTasks)

      Views.showTasks(allTasks)

      $new_task_input.focus()

      setTimeout (->
        $('#main-content').addClass('content-show')
      ), 150
```

Comment: Looks like CoffeeScript to me, not JS.

Comment: I guess `->` means braces

Comment: Yes you're correct, the source is Coffeescript. I can give you a link to the compiled, unminifed JS source if that's easier?

Comment: Don't know if that's easier then, but it sure wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Here's the compiled JS that runs on first load. There's a bit more here than I included in the question. http://pastebin.com/6st4ZxHs

Comment: @BenjaminHumphrey not required if you tag coffeescript in your question so that people who wanna solve your doubt can test it, also, recently I had the same issue, reason is that when you click on the popup chrome doesn't prefetch/cache anything so it hard refreshes the popup on every click, so I wrapped the entire thing in a function and executed with a 100 ms delay so that it doesn't interrupt the load of popup

Comment: @Mr.Alien So basically wrap the whole thing in a set timeout?

Comment: A function and then call that in settimeout, the reason I did this is because if something takes time to load chrome won't open the popup for you until it loads entire dom so settimeout gets handy here

Comment: Okay cool. I need to seriously refactor this whole document.ready / initialize part anyway, so I'll take the set timeout idea into consideration.

Comment: Add the whole `popup.html` too.

Comment: Simply comment out code until you detect what is slowing it down.

Comment: Also finding very odd that this has 3 upvotes when this is pretty broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the `checkOnline()` method was taking a wee while to return and blocked the rendering of the popup. This is the `checkOnline()` method, in Coffeescript:

```
checkOnline = ->
  online = navigator.onLine
  return online
```

The solution was to put this (and another method that relied on it) in a timeout so the rest of the JS could run and stop blocking the popup from being shown:

```
$(document).ready ->

  setPopupClass()

  standardLog()

  checkStorageMethod()

  window.tourRunning = false

  document.onkeydown = keyboardShortcuts

  tour = createTour() # This is badwrong

  initialize()

  setTimeout (->

    checkOnline()

    changeEmptyStateImage(online)

  ), 100
```